# Force inputText field to render empty

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Is there a way to render an inputText field competely empty even though the bean's attribute linked to it has a value?

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.attribute}"/>
```

--EDIT--
I can use jquery 1.9 and javascript.

Comment: Do you want it empty only on the initial request or also on subsequent ones?

Comment: Subsequent. As in each time it's rendered.

Comment: Try using two properties, one private one public. The public one writes through to the private one and resets itself to null.

Comment: it seems like you would just want to initialize your bean attribute on null - or empty

Comment: @Kmae the thing is that the attribute will never be null because it's an id. That's why I need to display an empty field "even though the bean's attribute linked to it has a value".

Comment: so the field has a value, but you want to overwrite it with another value? Or do you want to optionally overwrite the field? Either way, an extra field seems about right. You can not store two values in one field, even if business-wise that's what's required...